# How to detect device types connected in LAN

Tags: c#, networking, cisco

Currently I am able to get the ip, mac addresses and host name connected to my Network. But my goal is to detect either it's a mobile phone or a laptop. I know nmap but I want to do it by using c#. One of the application that is doing this LanSweaper but i am not able to figure out how can i do this. Looking for hints. Method currently i tried is port scanning (as of nmap).

Comment: The MAC address is returned in a PING Response.  The MAC contains the Manufacturer, Model, Serial number of the Ethernet interface.  You may or may not be able to determine if it is mobile or laptop depending on the numbering system that is used.  In a lot of cases it is the board containing the Ethernet Microcircuit.  So if a laptop manufacturer bought the board from another company it will not be the manufacturer of the laptop.  With cell phones, the it is more likely the phone manufacturer but often a phone is made and then sold to other companies that put there name on the phone.

Comment: So I need to interpret the Mac address to extract this sort of information right ?

Comment: Yes. There are lists available that gives the field.  You can find on the web.

Comment: Here one similar but with Objective-C https://github.com/netdiscover-scanner/netdiscover